# Browser stops working after switching virtual terminal

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, debian

On my debian, I have 2 desktop enviornments with 2 different users started at the same time (one personal and one for work). They are running on tty7 and tty8.

When I play music in the browser and I switch to the other tty, after maybe a minute the music stops playing. Switching back to the first tty, it continues playing from where it left. The same happens with video calls (going back to the first terminal I see a message "connection lost"). As far as I can tell, it happens for any site.

It appears that the browser is detecting being idle and pauses tabs. I see this in both Firefox 92 and Chrome 92 and it started happening after I upgraded the browsers. I tried disabling Chrome idle detection API but this doesn't fix the issue.

How can I disable this?

Comment: It looks like Firefox doesn't have idle detection, so it may be caused by something else. How about using only one tty but with 2 separate desktops?

Comment: @golimar I'm quite used to my current setup - files are split between the user accounts; I'm not distracted by personal chats while working (and vice versa).

Comment: Then you may use some program like Caffeine so that the session does not go idle, or try with another web browser

Comment: I still see the same issue with Caffeine enabled.